# HttpPost - type of http request method

Tags: java, android, http, post, http-post

Hi :) I got a simple problem, but very annoying. 
I'm trying to send http post request using HttpPost class

This is part of the method which returns InputStream:

```
           HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url+path); 
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> paramsList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        paramsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1", value1));
        paramsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key2", value2));
        paramsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key3", value3));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(paramsList));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
        return is;
```

But the problem is on the server, because server "thinks" that im sending GET request instead of POST. The question is: where is mistake? Im using similar part of code in other application and it works fine.

Cheers. :)

Comment: maybe you need to change your call to GET. What kind of service you have? is it php? php makes a clear distinction between post and get, and if it's expecting a parameter on GET it won't be able to get it from a POST.

Comment: webservice is expecting POST request, there is no chance to send parameters with GET :(

Comment: What makes you think the server is seeing a GET request?

Comment: I can see server logs. And the response of the server is empty,just like there were no parameters in request.

Comment: If you use GET then also rewrite url string as url+path+"?action=YOUR_WEB-SERVICE_NAME&parameter1name=value1&parameter2name=value2"

Comment: What is the exact value of `url+path` ?

Comment: http :// url/ path - I can't give you the specified value ;/. GET requests work fine , but I have to send big json so I need to use POST. This is weird, because the same method is working well in other project.

Comment: Then I can't help you. If there is question mark `?` in the url it might processed as a HTTP GET method. The code above should work fine. Check the server side, the problem might be there.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(paramsList, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

Instead Of

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(paramsList));
```

Comment: this is all, what I got in my method, the difference is in parameters only. I'm reading from input stream using BufferedReader and readLine() method.